# Rstan on Rstudio MCMC having too elevated running time (limited use of avaiable CPU and RAM)

Tags: r, rstudio, mcmc, stan, rstan

I am a newbie of the Rstan world, but I really need it for my thesis. I am actually using the script and a similar dataset from a guy from NYU, who reports as an estimated time for a similar DS of about 18 hours. However, when I try to run my model it won't do more than 10% in 18hours. Thus, I ask for some little help to understand what I am doing wrong and how to improve the efficiency.

I am running a 500 iter, 100 warmup 2 chains model with a Bernoulli_logit function over 5 parameters, trying to estimate 2 of them through a No U Turn MC procedure. (at each step it draws from a random normal a each parameters, then it estimates y and compares it with the actual data to see if the new parameters are a better fit to the data)

```
 y[n] ~ bernoulli_logit( alpha[kk[n]] + beta[jj[n]] - gamma * square( theta[jj[n]] - phi[kk[n]] ) );
```

(n being about 10mln)
My data is a 10.000x1004 matrix of 0s and 1s. To wrap it up, it is a matrix about people following politicians on twitter and I want to estimate their political ideas given who they follow. I run the model on RStudio with R x64 3.1.1 on a Win8 Professional, 6bit, I7 quad core with 16 GB ram.
Checking the performances, rsession uses no more than 14% CPU and 6GB of ram, although 7 more GB are free. While trying to subsample to a 10.000x250 matrix, I have noticed that it will use below 1.5GB instead. However, I have tried the procedure with a 50x50 dataset and it worked just fine, so there is no mistake in the procedure. 
Rsession opens 8 threads, i see activity on each core but none is fully occupied. 
I wonder why is it the case that my PC does not work at the best of its possibilities and whether there might be some bottleneck, a cap or a setup that prevents it to do so. R is 64 bit (just checked) and so Rstan should be (even though I had some difficulties in installing and that might have messed up some parameters)

this is what happens when i compile it

```
Iteration: 1 / 1 [100%]  (Sampling)
#  Elapsed Time: 0 seconds (Warm-up)
#                11.451 seconds (Sampling)
#                11.451 seconds (Total)

SAMPLING FOR MODEL 'stan.code' NOW (CHAIN 2).

Iteration: 1 / 1 [100%]  (Sampling)
#  Elapsed Time: 0 seconds (Warm-up)
#                12.354 seconds (Sampling)
#                12.354 seconds (Total)
```

while when i run it it just works for hours but it never goes beyond the 10% of the first chain (mainly because I have interrupted it after my pc was about to melt down).

```
Iteration:   1 / 500 [  0%]  (Warmup)
```

and has this setting:

```
stan.model <- stan(model_code=stan.code, data = stan.data, init=inits, iter=1, warmup=0, chains=2)

## running modle
stan.fit <- stan(fit=stan.model, data = stan.data, iter=500, warmup=100, chains=2, thin=thin, init=inits)
```

please help me find what is slowing down the procedure (and if nothing wtong is happening, what can I manipulate to have still some reasonable result in shorter time?).

I thank you in advance,

ML

here's the model (From Pablo Barbera, NYU)

```
n.iter <- 500
n.warmup <- 100
thin <- 2 ## this will give up to 200 effective samples for each chain and par

Adjmatrix <- read.csv("D:/TheMatrix/Adjmatrix_1004by10000_20150424.txt", header=FALSE)  
##10.000x1004 matrix of {0, 1} with the relationship "user i follows politician j"
StartPhi <- read.csv("D:/TheMatrix/StartPhi_20150424.txt", header=FALSE)  
##1004 vector of values [-1, 1] that should be a good prior for the Phi I want to estimate

start.phi<-ba<-c(do.call("cbind",StartPhi))
y<-Adjmatrix

J <- dim(y)[1]
K <- dim(y)[2]
N <- J * K
jj <- rep(1:J, times=K)
kk <- rep(1:K, each=J)

stan.data <- list(J=J, K=K, N=N, jj=jj, kk=kk, y=c(as.matrix(y)))

## rest of starting values
colK <- colSums(y)
rowJ <- rowSums(y)
normalize <- function(x){ (x-mean(x))/sd(x) }

inits <- rep(list(list(alpha=normalize(log(colK+0.0001)), 
                   beta=normalize(log(rowJ+0.0001)),
                   theta=rnorm(J), phi=start.phi,mu_beta=0, sigma_beta=1, 
                   gamma=abs(rnorm(1)), mu_phi=0, sigma_phi=1, sigma_alpha=1)),2)
##alpha and beta are the popularity of the politician j and the propensity to follow people of user i;
##phi and theta are the position on the political spectrum of pol j and user i; phi has a prior given by expert surveys
##gamma is just a weight on the importance of political closeness

library(rstan)

stan.code <- '
data {
int<lower=1> J; // number of twitter users
int<lower=1> K; // number of elite twitter accounts
int<lower=1> N; // N = J x K
int<lower=1,upper=J> jj[N]; // twitter user for observation n
int<lower=1,upper=K> kk[N]; // elite account for observation n
int<lower=0,upper=1> y[N]; // dummy if user i follows elite j
}
parameters {
vector[K] alpha;
vector[K] phi;
vector[J] theta;
vector[J] beta;
real mu_beta;
real<lower=0.1> sigma_beta;
real mu_phi;
real<lower=0.1> sigma_phi;
real<lower=0.1> sigma_alpha;
real gamma;
}
model {
alpha ~ normal(0, sigma_alpha);
beta ~ normal(mu_beta, sigma_beta);
phi ~ normal(mu_phi, sigma_phi);
theta ~ normal(0, 1); 
for (n in 1:N)
y[n] ~ bernoulli_logit( alpha[kk[n]] + beta[jj[n]] - 
gamma * square( theta[jj[n]] - phi[kk[n]] ) );
}
'

## compiling model
stan.model <- stan(model_code=stan.code, 
data = stan.data, init=inits, iter=1, warmup=0, chains=2)

## running modle
stan.fit <- stan(fit=stan.model, data = stan.data, 
iter=n.iter, warmup=n.warmup, chains=2, 
thin=thin, init=inits)

samples <- extract(stan.fit, pars=c("alpha", "phi", "gamma", "mu_beta",
                                "sigma_beta", "sigma_alpha"))
```

Comment: Hi Mario Luca, I am trying to run the same code as you (the Pablo Barbera code) and am having the same difficulty. Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

First, my apologies: I would have introduced this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.

Here's the question you asked: "what can I manipulate to have still some reasonable result in shorter time?"

The answer is, it depends. Instead of representing things as a binary matrix, have your tried reducing the size of the matrix by using counts? Based on the type of model you're trying to run, I imagine there is some non-identifiablity in the posterior. Could you try reparameterizing?

Also, you may want to run in CmdStan if R is causing problems with memory management.